# Do lightfoot halflings get +2 to Acrobatics?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, proficiency, halfling

I'm creating a lightfoot halfling bard via [5e Companion App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blastervla.ddencountergenerator), and it automatically added a proficiency to Acrobatics. Is that legit, or do I need to remove it?

Comment: What's your character's Background?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Are you asking about the +2 or the proficiency? What is the total skill modifier on acrobatic? If you can, please add what background you use for your character.

Comment: You might want to use the character generator on http://dndbeyond.com/ instead.

Answer (score 15):

### Lightfoot Halflings do not get any skill bonuses

They have the Lucky trait:

> When you roll a 1 on the d20 for an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll.

They have Brave:

> You have advantage on saving throws against being frightened.

They have Halfling Nimbleness:

> You can move through the space of any creature that is of a size larger than yours.

And they are Naturally Stealthy:

> You can attempt to hide even when you are obscured only by a creature that is at least one size larger than you.

They also get +2 Dex from the halfling race, and +1 Cha from the lightfoot halfling subrace.

Dexterity is tied to Acrobatics, and so the +2 racial bonus will increase Acrobatics by +1. Any proficiency with the skill would be from a class, background, or gear.